# Getting studentized residuals

Tags: r, statistics

I Have this matrix:

```
                        High    middle  low
              current    51       22     43 
               former    92       21     28
                never    68        9     22
```

and I am trying to figure out how I can get the studentized residuals, I tried to make this into a data frame. But I am not sure if there is a function in R where it can calculate its studentized residuals, preferably into table form. Ive looked online, and I am trying to find function so I can check my hand made calculations.

Comment: Are you sure you want studentized residuals? These are computed from the results of a linear regression. You seem to have a cross-tabulation so perhaps you want standardized residuals as part of a Chi Square test? How did you compute your hand made calculations?

Comment: Well I just obtained the standardized residuals from my expected values. I am unsure how to get the linear regression model for this table. I mostly want to obtain a linear model and a table of the residuals for each value. What is the main difference between the Studentized & Standardized? Is one more accurate?

Answer (score 1):

You should post your data using `dput` to make it easier to show you how to use your data. Your matrix probably has a structure like this assuming it is called `tbl`?

```
str(tbl)
#  int [1:3, 1:3] 51 92 68 22 21 9 43 28 22
#  - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
#   ..$ : chr [1:3] "current" "former" "never"
#   ..$ : chr [1:3] "High" "middle" "low"
```

To use regression you need to change the format:

```
dta <- as.data.frame.table(tbl)
dta
#      Var1   Var2 Freq
# 1 current   High   51
# 2  former   High   92
# 3   never   High   68
# 4 current middle   22
# 5  former middle   21
# 6   never middle    9
# 7 current    low   43
# 8  former    low   28
# 9   never    low   22
```

Now the `glm` function with `family=poisson`:

```
dta.glm <- glm(Freq~Var1+Var2, dta, family="poisson")
```

Now get a summary of the results and plot them:

```
summary(dta.glm)
plot(dta.glm)
```

Finally your studentized residuals:

```
rstudent(dta.glm)
#          1          2          3          4          5          6          7          8          9 
# -4.1411597  1.8519088  2.2282495  1.5779266  0.1239062 -1.9153422  3.1722502 -2.2230862 -1.0548112
```

Comment: Interesting, thank you. Also, would these values change because you are using the function family = poisson? This means Poisson distribution correct?

Comment: Yes they would change. This is a Poisson regression which is designed for dependent variables that are counts. For a simple linear regression use `dta.lm <- lm(Freq~Var1+Var2, dta)`.

Comment: Sweet, thank you. Also last question. how you used as.data.frame. Is this the same as using data.frame? or does it just depend on how you have your vectors/data set up?

Comment: Regression assumes that each row is an observation so we have to format each cell in your original table as a row. Your table would work fine with a Chi Square analysis to see if there was an interaction between your row and column variables. I just changed your 3 x 3 table to a 9 x 3 data frame showing how many observations there are for each combination of variable 1 and variable 2.